# Javascript prototype inheritance over multiple prototypes

Tags: javascript

i've got some problems with javascript prototype inheritance when this inheritance is stretched between multiple objects: surely i'm doing something wrong but for the moment i'm failing to understand what.

The whole Prototype's inheritance system seems to lose available methods when extending a prototype that already extends a prototype.

An example:

consider the following Objects

- object A

  - prototype with extended function ab
  - prototype with extended function cd
- object B

  - extends A
- object C

  - extends B
  - prototype with extended function ef
- object D

  - extends C

here an example of these Objects, as i have defined them:

*Object A*

```
function A () {
    this.someproperty = someValue;
}

A.prototype.ab = function () {
    // does something
}

A.prototype.cd = function () {
    // does something
}
```

*Object B*

```
function B () {
    A.call(this);

    this.someOtherProperty = someValue;
}

B.prototype = A.prototype;
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

*Object C*

```
function C () {
    B.call(this);
}

C.prototype = B.prototype;
C.prototype.constructor = C;

C.prototype.ef = function () {
    // does something
}
```

*Object D*

```
function D () {
    C.call(this);

    this.someOtherProperty = someValue;
}

D.prototype = C.prototype;
D.prototype.constructor = D;
```

given the example above, i am expecting that initializing a variable as "new D", such variable should have available the methods ab, cd, and ef, accessible with

- variable.ab()
- variable.cd()
- variable.ef()

It seems instead that all of these are undefined.

Please consider that if i initialize "new B" instead:

- variable.ab()
- variable.cd()

are defined and working

**am i doing something wrong or prototype inheritance cannot be over stretched over multiple objects?**

Thank you!

Comment: @mbojko's answer should work below.  How are you checking the properties of `new D()`?  For example `Object.keys(new D())` will give you the `someProperty` and `someOtherProperty` as these belong to the instance, but the methods do not and will not be listed.  `console.log((new D()).ab)` should still give you a function reference though.

Comment: In the future, please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.  Please consider rolling your edit back and accepting the answer that solved the problem.

Comment: checking again, @mbojko answer was the correct fix, also ES6 syntax was working correctly. Thank you all for the support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
B.prototype = A.prototype;
```

It's not inheritance, it's overwriting: `A.prototype` and `B.prototype` become the same object. It should be

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this as well, and will update my main answer, but the outcome is the same: the methods of A are undefined when a new D is instantiated

Comment: @Mith84 It is good to understand how it works under the hood, however I would suggest using the `class` syntax instead if you are going to use this kind of inheritance.  This way problems such as calling one of your constructors without `new` are taken care of.

Comment: @EuanSmith using ES6 syntax then solves the problem?

Comment: Yes `class B extends A {...}` see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)

Comment: I checked again: prototype extension is indeed working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code re-written with ES6 classes.  @mbojko's answer is quite correct (so please accept that one rather than this as @mbojko is directly answering your question), however if you are going to use deep levels of class inheritance of this kind (and many would argue that you shouldn't - I tend to feel for some problems it is the right approach but you certainly need to be cautious) I would suggest using ES6 classes instead - clearer syntax and more guards against incorrect usage.

```
class A{
  constructor (){
    this.someproperty = 0;
  }

  ab(){
    //...
    return "called ab method"
  }
  cd(){
    //...
  }
}

class B extends A{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.someOtherProperty = 1;
  }
}

class C extends B{
  ef(){
    //...
  }
}
class D extends C{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.someOtherProperty = 2;
  }
}

const d=new D();
console.log(d.ab());
```